# Why don't switch statements work with arrays?

Tags: javascript

The following alerts nothing. I assume everyone can see what I'm trying to accomplish. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

```
var myarray = ['foo', 'bar'];

switch (myarray) {

    case ['foo', 'bar']:
        alert('foobar');
        break;

    case ['foo', 'foo']:
        alert('foofoo');
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `['foo', 'bar']` does not equal another instance of `['foo', 'bar']`.  They are two distinct objects which happen to contain the same information.